# Good IDE for node.js + coffeescript + jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jasmine, webstorm

What good IDEs are there to develop with the combination of Jasmine, node.js and coffeescript.

So far, we're considering WebStorm, but it is really hard to get started. We find very little documentation on node.js (and coffeescript) in combination with the IDE.

What other options are there? (And are there any guides that can help us get started/up and running?)

**edit:**

- Me and my team are running Windows/OSX.
- Vim/Emacs is **not** an option. We need something with a graphical interface/an IDE.
- It must be easy to "get started" with node.js and coffee in the IDE. Preferably somewhat "tailored" for use with node.js.

  - WebStorm promises to do just that, however, getting started turns out to be pretty difficult. Running .coffee doesn't seem to work.

Thanks :)

Comment: What kind of documentation are you looking for? It's just an editor, and then you run Node; no problem. I use PyCharm (same core IDE as WebStorm) to edit CoffeeScript for node, and it works fine (apart from their CoffeeScript editor being terribly buggy).

Comment: There is no obvious way to run a .coffee script file. The "Compile to Javascript"-function, doens't do much except showing me what the code would look like in javascript. Am I supposed to copy that code, paste it into a javascript file and then run it with a html file? :S

Comment: If you're using it with Node.js, then no, you wouldn't run it with an HTML file, you'd run it with Node. Node runs *outside* the Web browser. Just do `coffee filename.coffee` from the command line.

Comment: that would probably work in linux, but in windows, command line never works (or I would have to locate the coffee.exe somehow manually). but, since it's an IDE that's supposed to support coffeescript, being able to run the code from the IDE should be possible..? :/

Comment: It works fine on Windows, I do it all the time. Sounds like you're having trouble getting Node / CoffeeScript installed properly; maybe you should post another question about that. As for running CoffeeScript from the IDE, WebStorm is meant for Web development, so I don't know if it has any Node integration like you want. (And even if it did, if you don't have CoffeeScript properly installed, it wouldn't work anyway, since it would just shell out to `coffee`.)

Comment: The command-line problem isn't specific to node. I have both ruby and lots of other applications that simply isn't recognized as words in the windows command line. Do I have to goto some windows PATH menu somewhere to configure it? As mentioned, command line *never* works, unless I manually navigate my self (with "cd") to the very folder that contains the .exe, which makes me hate my life :P  (thanks for helping me btw! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7077/discussion-between-joe-white-and-kornfridge)

Answer (score 2):

Komodo Edit (free to use) and Komodo IDE (requires paid license) support syntax highlighting for JavaScript and CoffeeScript. I believe call hints for node.js are provided.

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide

I can vouch for KomodoEdit as a good IDE in general; I've been using it in Python and PHP projects with satisfaction.

Be sure to start with the 7.0 release candidate; it's been RC for quite a while, and you could miss it if you start from the Komodo Edit home page. 6.0 is probably before CoffeeScript became popular.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, Komodo seems even less "tailored" (than WebStorm) for my specific use (Node.js and Coffeescript). I need some "whole package" solution for my team that "encourage" best practices. Being able to run .coffee and get started should be effortless...

Comment: @kornfridge what your looking for doesn't exist. There is no generic coffeescript IDE. There is defiantly no IDE that encourages "coffeescript best practices". You just have to know that and use lower level tools

Comment: More to the point of what Raynos says, CoffeeScript and Node.js are rather new. It takes time for application frameworks' and languages' ecosystems to acquire kitchen sink IDEs like Visual Studio. Define your requirements; pick an editor that gets you partway there; write docs and scripts that everyone will use with the chosen editor. (How to create a new Node.js app; Script to launch a Node.js app from this project, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It only works on OSX, but [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is fantastic for CoffeeScript. Make sure to use the [CoffeeScript TextMate bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle), which will run some useful CoffeeScript tasks with keyboard shortcuts.

I haven't tried it, but you might be able to get some of the same awesomeness with Windows using [E-TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/). I don't know how compatible the two are.

Answer (score -1):

try using vim and unix as your IDE.

They are pretty good.

[CoffeeScript, node and vim](http://thorstenlorenz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/how-to-make-node-js-coffeescript-and-jasmine-play-nice-with-vim/)

Comment: Sorry. We're using a combination of Windows and OSX, and we're not command-line experts. we would need something with a graphical interface. Updated question/problem description. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @kornfridge I recommend now is a good time to learn the command line. You can use powershell on windows to a similar effect. You can also swap vim for Sublime Text 2 if you don't like gVim on windows.

Comment: @kornfridge "Need a graphical interface" sounds like a "prefer". Also, there's gVim, a part of the regular windows Vim install, and Emacs is a GUI unless told otherwise. You can use things like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to have a Unix-like environment.

Comment: **Solved:** This problem is solved in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066905/ide-or-editor-for-node-jsexpress-and-coffeescript

The solution to my problems was **Sublime Text 2** -- http://www.sublimetext.com/2 -- This editor works beyond expectations. 
 -----------
CoffeeScript can auto-compile files/folders with `coffee -cw mydir`