# IDE or editor for Node.js+Express and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide, coffeescript, express

Preferably an **IDE**. Integrated **support for Subversion**/Git is a big plus as we are a group of 6 people working.

Vim/Emacs is not that popular with the other as it is very awkward and **hard to get started** and it **requires alot of effort to learn** which takes the focus away from our project.

We're all used to/familiar with Eclipse, so an **IDE that resembles Eclipse** would be a big plus as well.

Thanks :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good IDE for node.js + coffeescript + jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023810/good-ide-for-node-js-coffeescript-jasmine)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Sublime 2 should be the answer to all your troubles
http://www.sublimetext.com/2
but if you like eclipse, aptana should be nice to
http://aptana.com/

Comment: aptana is mediocre. Try webstorm 3 instead.

Comment: We've tried WebStorm. It's mediocre as well. It doesn't fully understand coffeescript it seems, and thus adds little functionality over a simple editor.

Sublime seems pretty decent; trying it out atm.

Comment: Update: Wow. This program is impressive. TextMate-ish, but seemingly even better. And cross platform too. :)

Comment: When it comes to CoffeScript -> JavaScript (compiling): "coffee -cw mydirectory" will listen to changes on .coffee files, and automatically compile them to javascript.

Comment: This is more than just accepted. This is truly barney-style awesomeness. http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation . After that, install CoffeeScript and Nodejs plugins from the plugininstaller.

Answer (score 4):

You should try Aptana or [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), the second one is not free, but worth the required value. WebStorm has a default Node.JS and Express project available. If you select to a new project you can start one with these options as well. The IDE has some nice code completion, good highlighting and a large group of addons to enhance your experience with a lot of new technology.

Answer (score 1):

You should get any Eclipse (or Aptana) and [install](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse) [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/). That will add Node.js support.
And Express wizard.

Eclipse for JavaEE developers goes with EGit.

Alternatily you can get full Eclipse with everything above pre-installed as [Nodeclipse NTS](http://sf.net/p/nodeclipse)

[There is](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/coffeescript-editor-quick-installer#.UYkLMTeW9zM) Coffee Editor, but no running, debugging support currently.

[Nodeclipse.org](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse). Current version is 0.3.1

> ### Features
>
> - Creating default structure for New Node Project and New Node Source File
> - JavaScript Syntax highlighting
> - Content Assistant
> - NPM support
> - Debugging - Breakpoint, Trace, etc... via [Eclipse debugger plugin for V8](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/)
>
> ### Installing
>
> Update Site : http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates
>
> ### Usage
>
> Check http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/
>   For debugging check
>   [Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger)

Comment: I am Nodeclipse contributor. And would love to help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's at least limited support for Cloud9 (IDE in the browser): http://cloud9ide.zendesk.com/entries/20559696-create-a-coffeescript-node-js-project

Here's a live compilation extension project:
https://github.com/tanepiper/cloud9-livecoffee-ext

Discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/cloud9-ide/browse_thread/thread/0ae17400825d01f9?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

This ide https://atom.io/ from github supports CoffeeScript pretty well. Works fast I particularly like the coloring. I peronally don't like Eclipse, Aptana or similar options, they are so heavy in my computer.

Answer (score -1):

**RubyMine 4.0** (Early Access, US$59 w/free upgrade to 4.0 release) has VCS support (git et al.), debugging, node support, like a full-blown IDE.  It also has CoffeeScript support, though it falls down (as I recall) on debugging --- you end up back in JavaScript land --- which is where I'm doing most of my work now.

I'm using it right now with node, express, and JavaScript (mostly) and CoffeeScript (little experiments).

I assume RubyMine is a superset of WebStorm (same company).  However, for $20 extra, you get ruby + JavaScript IDE, so I would suggest going with RubyMine if you have any inkling of doing ruby or rails in the near future.